# GeoJSON and Mongoose - Point must only contain numeric elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I'm getting the following error:

```
MongoError: Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5aba6a88d366dbbf6c83a5d3'), gpshits: [ { coordinates: [ 6.982654547382455, 46.88414220428685 ], _id: ObjectId('5aba6a8fd366dbbf6c83a5d4'), type: "Point" } ], licenseplate: "xxaa22", createdAt: new Date(1522166408205), updatedAt: new Date(1522166415372), __v: 0 }  Point must only contain numeric elements
```

Is it because i'm incorrectly nesting my Point in the model? I've read the docs but i cant find an example how to properly target the array. It's not giving any errors. Mainly trying to keep a log of GPS hits on a vehicle license plate number.

Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var VehicleSchema = new Schema({
        licenseplate: {type: String, required: true, unique:true},
        gpshits : [{
            type: { type: String },
            coordinates:[mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
        }]
    }, 
    { 
        timestamps: true
    }
);

VehicleSchema.index({'gpshits' : '2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vehicle', VehicleSchema);
```

Function:

```
function (req, res) {
        Joi.validate(req.body, Schemas.gpshit)
            .then(function () {
                return Vehicle.update({
                    licenseplate: req.body.licenseplate
                }, {
                    $push: {
                        'gpshits': req.body.hit
                    }
                }).exec();
            })
            .then(function () {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true
                });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
            });
    }
```

POST body:

```
{
    "licenseplate": "xxaa22",
    "hit" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates": [6.982654547382455, 46.88414220428685]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parseFloat where you Insert the lattitude and longitude in mongoDB

```
var vehicle = new vehicle({
                    "licenseplate": licenseNumber,
                    "loc": { 
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)]
                    }
                });
    vehicle.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by separating the array object into it's own schema and properly setting the coordinates field to '2dsphere' using index().

Comment: Setting properly the index in `2dsphere` works perfectly for me (even if I have a Dart server with `mongo_dart` and not with NodeJs, this worked after re-creating the index correctly).